# Date difference by different intervals

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am writing a query to get difference between two dates in three different intervals.

```
ID , D1           , D2
1  , '2013-01-01' , '2013-01-01'
2  , '2013-01-01' , '2013-02-01'
3  , '2013-01-01' , '2013-03-01'
4  , '2013-01-01' , '2013-07-01'
```

I want result by three categories : 1st week, one month and then 3 months,6 months, 9 months,etc..

```
case when round((DATEDIFF(D2,D1))/7,0) < 1 then  '1st week'
when round((DATEDIFF(D2,D1))/7,0) >1 and round((DATEDIFF(D2,D1))/7,0) <5  then  'one month' 
when ????
```

For the rest I am out of thinking.

Comment: What's the expected output for your query ?

Comment: one week, one month,3 month, 6 month for the above table.

Comment: Edit your post, so people don't have to read the comments to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
when YEAR(D2)*4+QUARTER(D2)-YEAR(D1)*4-QUARTER(D1)=1 then 'one quarter'
```

Then you can count quarters 3, 6, 9 monthes = 1, 2, 3 quarters accordingly

Comment: i think i this case i have to copy this line for each quarter i.e. = 1,2,3,4 to get quarters and also quarter for year 2013 and 2014 will appear as same

Comment: You can modify it to group by YEAR()+quarter difference

Comment: why are u multiplying year with 4.